# C# Item Templates and a variable for the project name?

Tags: c#, templates

Much of my code consists of three related classes, one based on an interface named IImplementation with a single Execute method (to help enforce single responsibility) and a response and context class.  I'm fed up of this, its laborious, repetitive and time consuming so today I decided to write a C# Item Template.

The template files and .vstemplate file look as follows:

**Implmentation.vstemplate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-sdkextension/2010">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Implementation</Name>
    <Description>Genertates a skeletal concrete IImplementation class complete with Response and Context classes.</Description>
    <Icon>Class.ico</Icon>
    <TemplateID>74206442-81cb-4328-afc8-08c40fb5d3e7</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
      <References>
          <Reference>
              <Assembly>System</Assembly>
          </Reference>
     </References>
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Implementation.cs</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs\$fileinputname$Response.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Response.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs\$fileinputname$Context.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Context.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
      <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
  <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WATemplateWizard />        </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

**Implementation.cs**

```
using System;
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Attibutes;
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Interfaces;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    [AutofacRegisterImplementation]
    public class $classname$ : 
        IImplementation<$classname$Response, $classname$Context>
    {
        #region Execute

        public $fileinputname$Response Execute($fileinputname$Context context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Response.cs**

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $classname$Response
    {
        #region Properties

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $classname$Context
    {
        #region Properties

        #endregion
    }
}
```

It kinda works great, I'm close to happy as I've even managed to nest the response and context classes beneath the implantation class which means less clutter in project files with lots of implementations (something I try very hard to avoid!)

[image: Nested response and context classes]

Except the following snippet from Implementation.cs:

```
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Attibutes;
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Interfaces;
```

Generates this (whole generated file):

```
using System;
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Attibutes;
using $safeprojectname$.Implementation.Interfaces;

namespace Balcony.Common.Implementation
{
    [AutofacRegisterImplementation]
    public class Test1 : 
        IImplementation<Test1Response, Test1Context>
    {
        #region Execute

        public Test1Response Execute(Test1Context context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This brings me to the conclusion $safeprojectname$ is only available to C# Project Templates.  Would this be correct?

Does anybody know how to get a safe project name variable to expand correctly in an C# Item Template?

Also while at it... How do you get it into the New from Template sub-menu?  And where can you steal the Class.ico files? :)

Comment: Despite the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eehb4faa(v=vs.140).aspx) I came to the same conclusion few month ago ...

Comment: It's the little things like this which make me hate Microsoft.  The only two product of theirs I use now are Word and VS  (oh mustn't fogrget the Snipping Tool).  Everything else is done on OS X.  It would have taken them 30 seconds to support this.

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this? It'd be great to have the safe project name for item templates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use $rootnamespace$ instead of the project name, that should do the same thing.