# Adding Custom File with aspx file using ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I am trying to create an Visual Studio `ItemTemplate` so that whenever we add `aspx` file in our Web Application project a text file should also be added along with that `aspx` as a sub-file. I am successfully able to create `ItemTemplate`. When we add a new `aspx` file using that custom `ItemTemplate`, it adds a `txt` file as well, but it does NOT appear as sub-item of `aspx` file.

[image]

As you can see `WebForm1.aspx.txt` this file is NOT appearing as a sub-item of `WebForm1.aspx` file which means it is appearing as a stand-alone item, if you delete the `WebForm1.aspx` file, it is NOT going to delete that `txt` file.

Here is the `vstemplate` file,

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>WebForm.aspx</DefaultName>
    <Name>WebForm with Text File</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="ASPXCodeBehind" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx.designer.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx.txt" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.txt</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK answer seems to be very simple, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442512/c-sharp-item-templates-and-a-variable-for-the-project-name) actually helped me.

We just need to add the actual file name before the child file name in `TargetFileName` attribute

E.g. `TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx\$fileinputname$.aspx.txt"`

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>WebForm.aspx</DefaultName>
    <Name>WebForm with Text File</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="ASPXCodeBehind" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx.designer.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.aspx\$fileinputname$.aspx.txt" ReplaceParameters="true">WebForm1.aspx.txt</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```